# Why won't ng-options populate this dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here's my json

[{"year":"1980","Manufacturer":"Oldsmobile","Model":"Cutlass","Product":""},{"year":"1980","Manufacturer":"Oldsmobile","Model":"Sierra","Product":""},{"year":"1980","Manufacturer":"Toyota","Model":"4Runner","Product":""},{"year":"1980","Manufacturer":"Ford","Model":"Fiesta","Product":""},{"year":"1980","Manufacturer":"GMC","Model":"Terrain","Product":""}]

and my HTML

```
<label class="item item-select">
<span class="input-label">
Select
</span>
<select ng-model="data.make" ng-options="make.Manufacturer for make in 
makes">
</select>
</label>
```

I'm probably missing something very basic here. The data is accessible in $scope.data.makes in the console.

Edited to add my javascript

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, getProducts) {

$scope.data = {
   "year" : $stateParams.year,
   "make" :""
}


$scope.data.makes =    getProducts.getMakesByYear($scope.data.year).then(function(data){})


}
```

edited to add my function:

```
var ret = {
    all: function(){

        return $http.get(api_url).then(function(resp){

            return resp.data;
        });

    },

    single: function(id){




        return $http.get(api_url+"search?Id="+id).then(function(resp){

            return resp.data;
        });

    },

  getMakesByYear: function(year){




        return $http.get(car_url+"search?year="+year).then(function(resp){

            return resp.data;
        });


    }
}



ret.all();

return ret;
```

}]);

Comment: Are you sure the data is coming back from your function getMakesByYear?

Comment: Reasonably. Console logging the return shows this: http://prntscr.com/l47t2p

Comment: I was console logging it on the http response, not the function return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't populating because you're setting data.makes to a promise instead of setting it to the array that the promise returns

you can fix it by calling the function when the controller initializes

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, getProducts) {

$scope.data = {
   "year" : $stateParams.year,
   "make" :"",
   "makes" : []
}

getProducts.getMakesByYear($scope.data.year).then(function(data){
   $scope.data.makes = data;
})
}
```

also... make sure you're using the correct variable `data.makes` instead of `makes`

`<select ng-model="data.make" ng-options="make as make.Manufacturer for make in data.makes">`

If the function is returning usable json then it should work with data.makes instead of just makes because makes is not directly on the scope

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do it.  Thank you for the attempt, though

Comment: Sorry... I missed the last part of your sentence before... the key is makes isn't directly on the scope... so you use ```data.makes``` instead

Comment: Still no luck, I've updated to read:     <select ng-model="data.make" ng-options="make as make.Manufacturer for make in data.makes">

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not working because your function returns a promise

Comment: You sir, are a genius.